# UUID in Windows

Tags: window, uuid

I'm searching for a some sort of unique windows/machine-internal ID which can be read using "CMD". I found the UUID/GUID which can be read like this:

`wmic csproduct get uuid`

I couldn't find a proper definition of what it REALLY is.
Whether it comes from Windows, or from the Bios, or where exactly from?

On what does it depend, will it change, e.g. when changing the graphics card, RAM, or cloning my Windows installation to a new hard-drive? So is it hardware-components dependent?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.nextofwindows.com/the-best-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-windows-machine

That UUID comes from your motherboard (and therefore will nit change) but you might want to use a hard drive serial number as a fallback if the UUID is not available.

Comment: Thasnks for the answer, is it possible to only show the Serialnumber of a certain volume, e.g. of drive `C:\ ` to avoid having to parse the output of `wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber` in case of multiple harddisks installed on the machine?